# how to change bootstrap class with changing values in react js?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

i want to change the bootstrap class with value query in react js...?

```
const Card = ({ item }) => {

  return (
   if (item.approval === "pending") {
   <span className="badge badge-danger">{item.approval}</span>

   } else if (item.approval === "Appropriate") {
   <span className="badge badge-warning">{item.approval}</span>

   } else if (item.approval === "approved") { 
   <span className="badge badge-success">{item.approval}</span>
   }
  )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use if statement inside `return`. You need to use it outside.

You can make it simple like this.

```js
const Card = ({ item }) => {
  let colorClassName = "badge-danger";
  if (item.approval === "Appropriate") colorClassName = "badge-warning";
  if (item.approval === "approved") colorClassName = "badge-success";

  return (
   <span className={`badge ${colorClassName}`}>{item.approval}</span>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: ``<span className=`badge ${colorClassName}`>{item.approval}</span>``  this code is getting error... Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text?

Comment: Try this  ```<span className={`badge ${colorClassName}`}>{item.approval}</span>```